If $u$, $v$ and $w$ are the digits of decimal system, then the rational number represented by $0.uw\overline{uv}$ is?
Context
I was recently giving a math test and encountered the following question:
If $u$, $v$ and $w$ are the digits of decimal system, then the rational number represented by $0.uw\overline{uv}$ is?
My approach
I initially asiigned this decimal expansion and multiplied by powers of 10 so that I could cancel out the decimals and make it easy:
$$ x = 0.uw\overline{uv}     ...(i)$$
$$ 10x = u.w\overline{uv}     ...(ii)$$
$$ 100x = uw.\overline{uv}     ...(iii)$$
$$ 1000x = uwu.v\overline{uv}     ...(iv)$$
$$ 10000x = uwuv.\overline{uv}     ...(v)$$
Then I subtracted (iii) from (v):
$$ 10000x - 100x = uwuv.\overline{uv}      - uw.\overline{uv}$$
$$9900x=uwuv - uw$$
$$x = \frac{1000u + 100w + 10u +v - 10u -w}{9900}$$
$$x = \frac{1000u + 99w + v}{9900}$$
But, the correct answer was $\frac{99uw +uv}{9900}$
Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

It's the same. It looks different because $uw$ denotes concatenation, not multiplication. When you expand it you will receive the same result.
I prefer your answer as notation $99uw$ might confuse someone.
Seeing it I would think $99 \times u \times w$ while it actually means $99 \times (10u + w)$.
